# How can I make a program to get recognized by Windows for "open with..." operations?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

How do I make a program to get recognized by Windows for "**open with...**" operations?

I wrote a text editor in python and made the .exe with pyinstaller, is there a way to insert it among the programs used by Windows to open txt files?

Comment: You'll need to add it to the registry. Look for the "Supported Types" key ("Lists the file types that the application supports. Doing so enables the application to be listed in the cascade menu of the Open with dialog box.") in [the official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: First you should create a program identifier (ProgId) with an "open" action, which can be defined in "[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\Classes\Applications\<YourApplicationName.exe>" (substitute your actual EXE name; *do not* set this via HKCR). Add a "shell\open\command" subkey, and the default value should be the template command, e.g. `"Path\To\YourApplicationName.exe" "%1"`. You can add other actions here in addition to "open", which will appear on the right-click context menu if your application owns the filetype. For use elsewhere, the name of this ProgId is "Applications\<YourApplicationName.exe>".

Comment: Since .txt files have a "text" `PerceivedType`, one way to add your application to the open-with menu is by appending the EXE name as a subkey under "[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\text\OpenWithList". Note that if you define "...\Applications\<YourApplicationName.exe>\SupportedTypes", it will act as a filter to remove your app from all "text" types that you haven't explicitly listed in your "SupportedTypes". So generally you don't need to define "SupportedTypes"; it's not where you set your program as a handler for the type in "Default Programs" anyway.

Comment: To set your app as a default handler, under your main registration key, e.g. "[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\<YourApplicationName>", create a "Capabilities" key that defines the text values "ApplicationName" and "ApplicationDescription". Under this, create a "FileAssociations" subkey. Add a text value for each association, e.g. set a ".txt" value to your application ProgID "Applications\<YourApplicationName.exe>". Then under "[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\RegisteredApplications" add a text value "YourApplicationName" that's the relative path of your "Capabilities" key.

Comment: Another way to get on the open-with menu is via the filetype's "OpenWithProgIds" subkey. This way has the advantage that it allows your app to implicitly  become the owner of the filetype (e.g. use your icon and additional context-menu actions) when the user selects it via open with, without requiring the user to explicitly "always use" your app (assuming it's not already explicitly owned). Create an "OpenWithProgIds" subkey of "[HKLM|HKCU]\Software\Classes\.txt" if it doesn't already exist, and an empty text value with your ProgId, e.g. "Applications\<YourApplicationName.exe>".

Comment: Once you've set things up, you need to notify the shell of your changes via [`SHChangeNotify`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762118). Bear in mind that Explorer caches a filetype's open with actions under "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts". Sometimes it seems to ignore a change. You can delete the "OpenWithList" and "OpenWithProgIds" subkeys of an extension in this key prior to calling `SHChangeNotify`; I don't know a better way. But don't delete a "UserChoice" subkey. You have no right to override a user's explicit choice.

Comment: Thanks for your help @eryksun and usr2564301

Comment: @eryksun: shall I gather all of our comments in an answer, so OP can accept it?

Comment: @usr2564301, you can add an answer if you want. I was waiting for constructive feedback from the OP in terms of what was tried and precisely what behavior is deisred. It's not a simple task, depending on how the OP wants the shell to handle the application for the "open with" menu. It's one of those questions that seems simple on the surface, but the answer could grow to several pages if not constrained.

Comment: @eryksun: I agree – it would not be a complete answer. (Part of the reason I only commented for the registry part, not as an answer.) Hopefully OP will be able to make it work from here and *then* add an answer, listing what parts were helpful.